# Create a generic find function for mongodb in Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm trying to create a method to which I can pass a mongodb connection pool, an objectId and the collection name to retrieve data.

I came up with the code below but which doesn't compile because of the following error:

> error: the method `find_one` exists for struct
> `mongodb::Collection<T>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
> label: method cannot be called on `mongodb::Collection<T>` due to
> unsatisfied trait bounds note: the following trait bounds were not
> satisfied: `T: DeserializeOwned` `T: Unpin` `T: std::marker::Send` `T: Sync` label: method cannot be called on `mongodb::Collection<T>` due
> to unsatisfied trait bounds

What I'm I doing wrong?

```
pub async fn generic_find_by_id<T>(db: &AppContext, object_id: String, collection_name: &str) -> Option<T> {
    let collection = db.mongodb_pool.collection::<T>(collection_name);
    
    let id_obj = ObjectId::parse_str(object_id);

    let found = match id_obj {
        Ok(id) => {
            let filter = doc! {"_id": id};
            let result = collection.find_one(filter, None).await;
            match result {
                Ok(result) => {
                    match result {
                        Some(result) => {
                            return Some(result);
                        }
                        None => {
                            return None;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    return None;
                }
            }
        }
        Err(_) => {
            return None;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Collection<T>::find_one()` is only implemented if `T: DeserializeOwned + Unpin + Send + Sync`. (See it in the source here: https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/src/mongodb/coll/mod.rs.html#795). I think `Send` and `Sync` have to do with the collection being potentially sent across threads during async function calls. To solve this, you can make your `T` type implement `Unpin` and `DeserializeOwned`. (`T` automatically implements `Send` and `Sync` if all `T`'s members are `Send` and `Sync`.)

Comment: I think I have same issue, can you give example ?? ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77206788/method-cannot-be-called-on-struct-has-generic-due-to-unsatisfied-trait-bounds-wh

Comment: @iuerui I'm not currently thinking in Rust, so writing up an example would take more time than I have at the moment. But on your question, someone suggested you post a minimum reproducible example. That's a good idea, that way people can run your code and play around with it even if they don't understand the problem/solution at first glance. (If your question happens to get closed before that, feel free to post it again with the full example code that shows the issue--there's no harm in a do-over.)