# method cannot be called on struct has generic due to unsatisfied trait bounds when forward the generic on functions

Tags: mongodb, generics, rust

I have trait like this

```
pub trait Repository {
    fn insert_one<T, D>(&self, col_name: EnumCollectionModel, doc: T) -> Result<(), ErrorIdentifier>
        where
            T: Borrow<mongodb::bson::Document>
    ;
}
```

in the implementation on above **trait** method

```
// D is for the Collection struct , eg: MyStructModel
let insert_result = self.database.collection::<D>(col_name.as_str()).insert_one(doc, None).await;
```

and on my Service impl

```
repository.insert_one::<mongodb::bson::Document, MyStructModel>(EnumCollectionModel::MyStructModelName, data.to_doc().unwrap());
```

then I got **error**:

```
...collection::<D>(col_name.as_str()).insert_one(doc, None).await;
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on 
`Collection<D>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

the `Collection<D>` in the Mongo Driver lib something like this

```
  pub fn collection<T>(&self, name: &str) -> Collection<T> {
        Collection::new(self.clone(), name, None)
    }
```

did you think I did wrong implementation for Generic `D` on this case to forward it from functions ?

Comment: Its very hard to say for certain since your code snippets are so fragmented. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so someone can copy your code and investigate the error. On its face though, you appear to be trying to insert a `Document` into a `Collection` of a different (generic) type.

Comment: It might also just be a missing bound on the parameter `D` in above definition of `insert_one`. The *full* error message will be helpful if that's the case.

Comment: the error message only like that when I run cargo, I want MyStructModel implement on the Collection<T>